# to fetch the data from file upload box through jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have implemented contact form 7 in my site now I want to get the value of file input box using the [`attr('value', val)` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr).

It was working when I run it in my Firefox console, but it did not work when I used in my file.

My code is like written below :

```
var val = jQuery(".filebrowse").val();
jQuery('.file-input').attr('value', val);
```

My contact form 7 input file  box have a class `.filebrowse` and I want to fetch its value to my input box which class is `.file-input`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".filebrowse").each(function(index,value){

  jQuery('.file-input')[index].val(value);

});
```